# Remove some folders from the file.getpath() Java

Tags: java, file, path, directory, filepath

So for example our      file.getPath()     returns "Data\Cache\Character\images\1.png"
Now what I want to do.. is to make String or another path or something to be: "Character\images\1.png" So removing those 2 first folders from the beginning. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this using the `Path` API very easily:

```
final Path image = Paths.get("/", "Data", "Cache", "Character", "images", "1.png");
final Path base = Paths.get("/", "Data", "Cache");
System.out.println(image);
System.out.println(base);
final Path relativeImage = base.relativize(image);
System.out.println(relativeImage);
```

Output:

```
\\Data\Cache\Character\images\1.png
\\Data\Cache\
Character\images\1.png
```

Comment: Thanks! This one works great! I just wonder why you use those "/" marks there? I'm making it without those and it still works just perfect?

Comment: Depends whether you want a _relative_ path or an absolute one.